# Ajuda com o laço while em um questionário em Python

Tags: python, loop, while

A intenção é se a resposta for `s` ele executa que concluiu o cadastro com sucesso, porem caso seja `n` ou diferente de `s` imprime a mensagem: *cadastro cancelado ou agradecemos e volte logo!*.

```
resposta = ''
while (resposta.upper() != 's'):
    resposta = input('Confirma seu cadastro? ')
    if resposta == 's':
        break
    print('Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!')

    else:
        if resposta != 's' or resposta == 'n':
        print('agradeçemos por seu interesse, volte logo!')
```

Comment: `resposta = ''
while (resposta.upper() != 's'):
    resposta = input('Confirma seu cadastro? ')
    if resposta == 's':
        
        print('Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!')
        break

    elif(resposta != 's' or resposta == 'n'):
          print('agradeçemos por seu interesse, volte logo!') ` teste isto

Comment: Luiz Augusto, obrigado amigo, deu certinho.